# ¿Cómo hacer para que al escanear con una pistola láser no me envíe los datos automáticamente?

Tags: php, html, código-de-barras

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de la mano de PHP de un control de ingreso y salida con Bootstrap. He presentado una dificultad: que al momento en que se escanea el código de barras, los datos los envía automáticamente con el primer botón como si fuera un *enter*. Lo que requiero es saber cómo puedo hacer para evitar que se envíe y solamente queden los datos ahí en el formulario y de una manera manual el usuario oprima el ingreso o la salida.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Inicio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/estilos/estilos.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="public/pnotify/css/pnotify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="public/pnotify/css/pnotify.buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="public/pnotify/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f40a589ae9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="public/pnotify/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="public/pnotify/js/pnotify.js"></script>
  <script src="public/pnotify/js/pnotify.buttons.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-logo" href="index.php">
        <img src="./img/remolab.png" style="max-height: 60px;">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="./vista/login/login.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Ingresar</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


<div class="container mt-3">
    <h3 class="text-center">Control de Ingreso y Salida</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="./img/grupo.png" style="width: 180%; margin-left: -430px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">

            <h3 class="mt-5">Bienvenido</h3>
            <h3 id="hora"></h3>
            <h3 id="fecha"></h3>
            <?php
            include "modelo/conexion.php";
            include "controlador/controlador_registrar_ingreso.php";
            include "controlador/controlador_registrar_salida.php";
            ?>
            <form id="registroForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data";>
                <div class="form-floating mb-4" style="max-width: 700px;">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="txtdniingreso" name="txtdniingreso" autocomplete="off" >
                    <label for="codigo-ingreso">Escanea el Código de Barras Para el Ingreso</label>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-4" role="group" aria-label="Botones de ingreso y salida">
                    <button class="btn btn-success me-2 ingresoBtn" value="Consultar" name="btnentrada" type="submit">Ingreso</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger salidaBtn" value="Consultar" name="btnsalida" type="submit">Salida</button>
              </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <script>
    function capitalizarPrimeraLetra(str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      let fecha = new Date();
      let opcionesFecha = {
        weekday: 'long',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric'
      };
      let fechaFormato = fecha.toLocaleDateString(undefined, opcionesFecha);
      fechaFormato = fechaFormato.split(' ').map((word, index) => (index > 0 ? ' ' : '') + capitalizarPrimeraLetra(word)).join(' ');
      document.getElementById("fecha").textContent = fechaFormato;

      let opcionesHora = {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        second: 'numeric',
        hour12: false
      };
      let horaFormato = fecha.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, opcionesHora);
      document.getElementById("hora").textContent = horaFormato;
    }, 10);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["btnentrada"])) {
    if (!empty($_POST["txtdniingreso"])) {
        $dni = $_POST["txtdniingreso"];
        $consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total, GROUP_CONCAT(nombre) as nombre FROM empleado WHERE dni='$dni'");
        $id = $conexion->query("SELECT id_empleado FROM empleado WHERE dni='$dni'");

        $resultadoConsulta = $consulta->fetch_object();

        if ($resultadoConsulta->total > 0) {
            $nombre = $resultadoConsulta->nombre;
            $id_empleado = $id->fetch_object()->id_empleado;

            $fecha = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
            $sql = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO asistencia(id_empleado, entrada) VALUES ($id_empleado, '$fecha')");

            if ($sql == true) { ?>
                <script>
                    $(function notificacion() {
                        new PNotify({
                            title: "CORRECTO",
                            type: "success",
                            text: "Hola <?= $nombre ?>, ¡Bienvenido!",
                            styling: "bootstrap3"
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <script>
                    $(function notificacion() {
                        new PNotify({
                            title: "INCORRECTO",
                            type: "error",
                            text: "Error al registrar ingreso",
                            styling: "bootstrap3"
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            <?php }
        } else {   ?>
            <script>
                $(function notificacion() {
                    new PNotify({
                        title: "INCORRECTO",
                        type: "error",
                        text: "El código no existe",
                        styling: "bootstrap3"
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php }
    } else { ?>
        <script>
            $(function notificacion() {
                new PNotify({
                    title: "INCORRECTO",
                    type: "error",
                    text: "Escanee el Código de barras",
                    styling: "bootstrap3"
                });
            });
        </script>
<?php }
} ?>

<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    }, 0);
</script>
```

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["btnsalida"])) {
    if (!empty($_POST["txtdnisalida"])) {
        $dni = $_POST["txtdnisalida"];
        $consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total, GROUP_CONCAT(nombre) as nombre FROM empleado WHERE dni='$dni'");
        $id = $conexion->query("SELECT id_empleado FROM empleado WHERE dni='$dni'");

        $resultadoConsulta = $consulta->fetch_object();

        if ($resultadoConsulta->total > 0) {
            $nombre = $resultadoConsulta->nombre;
            $fecha = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
            $id_empleado = $id->fetch_object()->id_empleado;

            $busqueda = $conexion->query(" SELECT id_asistencia FROM asistencia WHERE id_empleado=$id_empleado ORDER BY id_asistencia DESC LIMIT 1  ");
            $id_asistencia = $busqueda->fetch_object()->id_asistencia;
            $sql = $conexion->query(" UPDATE asistencia SET salida='$fecha' WHERE id_asistencia=$id_asistencia ");

            if ($sql == true) { ?>
                <script>
                    $(function notificacion() {
                        new PNotify({
                            title: "CORRECTO",
                            type: "success",
                            text: "Adios! <?= $nombre ?>, Vuelve pronto!",
                            styling: "bootstrap3"
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <script>
                    $(function notificacion() {
                        new PNotify({
                            title: "INCORRECTO",
                            type: "error",
                            text: "Error al registrar salida",
                            styling: "bootstrap3"
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            <?php }
        } else {   ?>
            <script>
                $(function notificacion() {
                    new PNotify({
                        title: "INCORRECTO",
                        type: "error",
                        text: "El código no existe",
                        styling: "bootstrap3"
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php }
    } else { ?>
    <script>
            $(function notificacion() {
                new PNotify({
                    title: "INCORRECTO",
                    type: "error",
                    text: "Escanee el Código de barras",
                    styling: "bootstrap3"
                });
            });
        </script>
<?php }
} ?>

<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    }, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: Revisa el manual del lector, normalmente puedes configurar el caracter que se envía inmediatamente después de hacer una lectura, bien podrías quitarlo o cambiarlo por tabulador.

Comment: Qué tal si guardas el código en una variable intermedia y cuando lo quieres cargar simplemente copias el valor de la variable o algo así?

Comment: imagina que el lector es como un teclado programable, cuando lees algo esto ocurre en el frontend, puedes manejarlo con javascript ... no tiene sentido por que tiene esto mesclado con php... que relacion hay ??? cual es el Error???

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover entiendo lo que me dice, tan solo no encuentro como hacerlo con un script y  tampoco estoy hablando de error

Comment: @Sal, perfecto, voy a mirar si por ahi se puede hacer algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previene el evento cuando se presione la tecla enter sobre el input para evitar que se genere el submit, este seria el código de ejemplo:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        input = document.querySelector("#txtdniingreso");
        input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') e.preventDefault();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: seria bueno agregar que por defecto las pistolas de barra terminan en un enter, lo que hace que se dispare el formulario al post, y luego agregar tu solucion